# make this short matlab loop more efficient

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make this loop run more efficiently.

Some introduction about the arguments:

A is 2 dimensional array. B is 1 dimensional array. The rest are integers.

Here is the Code:

```
for k = c:len_sim 
    A(k,1:(end-k+c)) = A(k,1:(end-k+c)) + B((k-c+1):end); 
end
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You operate on rows, not columns. Since matrices in Matlab are column-wise, the following code is more efficient:

```
for k = c:len_sim 
    A(1:(end-k+c),k) = A(1:(end-k+c),k) + B((k-c+1):end); 
end
```

An example system on my computer:

```
A = rand(3000, 3000);
B = rand(3000, 1)';

c = 10;
len_sim = c+1000;
```

Times (your implementation and mine)

```
Elapsed time is 0.114862 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.038503 seconds.
```

So you get 3 times speedup for just transposing your system. Of course, if you need to explicitly do the transpose it may not be worth it. But if you can reformulate your entire algorithm, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
k=c:len_sim;
A(k,1:(end-k+c)) = A(k,1:(end-k+c)) + B((k-c+1):end);
```

Comment: I have tried this ofcourse. The problem is that if you choose to iterate over k, A(k,1:(end-k+c)) is 2 dimensional and B((k-c+1):end) is one dimensional so matrix dimensions do not agree...

Comment: so your first call is the best I can see, nothing more I have to say about that without knowing what are A and B

Comment: thanks. i've also tried extending your code by using repmat() on B and unfortunately its slower.  I guess the best way to handle this one is parallel computing.